# Linear Sequences and Repeating Series for beginners!

Tags: sequences-and-series

My eleven year old grandson has just started senior school and is receiving assistance for his dyslexia.

Amongst his home work are a series of questions relating to Linear Sequences, Repeating Series etc, most of which I think I can help him with, but I am nearly 72.

There is one question that I am not understanding, namely:

"How many different linear sequences can you create where the last digits are always a repeating series?"

Can any one out there help ASAP, given our ages i.e. 11 and 71?

Comment: Isn't the number infinite? Proof by contradiction: Assume that there are finitely many such sequences. Now take the first term of all of those sequences. Since the list is finite, you can take the maximum of those. Add one to that, and create a sequence that starts with that number. Now you have a new sequence where the last digits repeat. Contradiction. Or am I missing something?

Comment: Not enough information to decide what the problem statement means. Perhaps give more information such as other questions or instructions for the homework. Otherwise ask the teacher who set the homework.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, as I understood it a linear series is a list of numbers that increases or decreases by the same amount each time and a repeating series is a list of numbers with a recurring pattern. If the increment is strictly positive or negative, then the series won't repeat (because it will keep rising or plumetting). This means that the only possible increment is 0. There are an infinite amount of constant series that all satisfy this, so the answer is infinity.

Do tell if I misunderstood the definitions.